# Get exact mail message after calling mail() - PHP

Tags: php, email

After calling the mail function I would like to get the complete mail message that I just sent. Not just the subject and content field but also auto generated information such as Date and Content-Transfer-Encoding. That is the entire message. How do I do that?

Comment: Not possible AFAIK. Maybe with a 3rd party library, if even there. But definitely not with `mail()`.

Comment: If you can't adapt the local `sendmail` binary to store a copy, then investigate something more contemporary PHP-side. SwiftMailer or PHPMailer come to mind, and certainly already provide a raw result dump.

Comment: can be done using the mail servers log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP doesn't actually send the mail, so *it* won't know about any of that. All the `mail()` function does is pass your stuff on to the *sendmail* binary (or whatever SMTP server you use instead) and return whether or not that was successful. The rest is up to the SMTP server.

Best suggestion I can offer is to have the mail BCCd to an account you control and parse the desired info from there.

Comment: This is actually the answer I was looking for since it's not possible to get the exact mail message.